# How do I expand my camera distance?

Tags: camera

I already know how to expand the distance with a normal camera view. But how do I expand it, with the work camera? Or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the render distance in your viewport, increase the `End` field in the view properties panel.

[image: clip]

Show the properties panel by pressing N, then go into the view tab to change the setting.